# Как получить некий js-код отдельно как код, отдельно как строку?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars

Пишу приложение для документации некоторого внутреннего фреймворка.
В этом приложении должны быть помимо всего прочего две секции:

Секция один, исходный код, конфигурирующий некоторый наш компонент, что-то вроде:

```
var MegaComponent = new core.form.awesomeThings.SuperComponent({
                    model: this.model,
                    someProperty: true,
                    otherProperty: 'blahblah',
                    yetAnotherProperty: {}
                });
```

Секция два, собственно визуальное отображение компонента с такими свойствами. То есть что будет если мы создадим мегакомпонент и бросим его на нашу формочку.

Собственно по сути и то и то - практически одна сущность. И если мы хотим что-то в конфигурации нашего компонента изменить, было бы классно сделать это в одном месте, а не отдельно лезть в скрипт, отдельно в html-шаблон.

То есть в итоге нам надо либо выполнить код из строки, либо получить какой-то кусок кода как строку из него самого, либо организовать какую-то систему, по вытягиванию кода отдельно как кода и отдельно как текста.

**Вопрос: есть ли какие-то подходы к решению такой задачи, о которых я не подумал?**

Если это поможет, то приложение - это SPA на `Backbone.Marionette` побитое на `require` модули и использующее `handlebars` как шаблонизатор.

**Варианты, которые я придумал:**

Можно хранить примеры кода в некотором большом шаблоне/множестве мелких, отрисовывать его, тянуть его внутренности и превращать их в исполняемый код с помощью `eval`.

Впрочем наверное можно хранить и не в шаблоне, а в отдельных скриптфайлах, тянуть их аяксом и опять же ивалить когда надо.

Вариант "обернуть в функцию" и делать ей `toString` мне совсем не нравится, потому что во-первых ее покромсает минификатор, во-вторых `toString` может сожрать форматирование кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил так:

С помощью [плагина text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) для requirejs можно спокойно грузить файлы как текст используя префис `text!` Обычно это используется для загрузки html-темплейтов, но js-файлы он тоже спокойно понимает и может грузить не исполняя. Потом содержимое можно прогнать через `eval`.

```
require(["text!cases/testcase.js"],
    function(testcase) {
         console.log(testcase);
         eval(testcase);
    }
);
```

Comment: eval же не нужен, handlebars Вы используете. Пишите registerHelper во вью и он собирает Вам весь демо-блок. И код и компонент.

Comment: @shatal, благодарю, сейчас попробую